# Dojox.grid.DataGrid filtering

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I've a DataGrid which contains data fetched from the server side. I need to filter the data based on some conditions. I've three checkboxes, on selecting the checkboxes I need to filter the data. For example I've three Checkboxes- Pending, Issued,Completed. When I uncheck Pending checkbox, the DataGrid should contain only Issues and Completed.
I'm able to filter a single element by using

```
dataGrid.filter({status: 'P*'});
```

But I'm not able to give the OR conditions, I tried Piped character, still it didn't work. Can someone please suggest me a way to implement this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at using the dojo.data.AndOrReadStore.  It supports more complex queries.